# Verification of my solution to a question on Analytic function about its image

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

I want to verify if my reasoning is appropriate for the following question.

**Let $U \subset \mathbb{C}$ be an open connected set and $f: U \to \mathbb{C}$ be a non constant analytic function. Consider the following two sets:**

$\begin{align}
&X= \{z \in U: f(z)=0\}\\
&Y= \{z \in U: f \text{ vanishes on an open neighbourhood of $z$ in $U$} \}
\end{align}$

**Then which of the following statements are true?**

- $X$ is closed in $U$.
- $Y$ is closed in $U$.
- $X$ has empty interior.
- $Y$ is open in $U$.

*My reasoning:*
All the options are correct as:

- Since $X= f^{-1}\{0\}$ and being inverse image of closed set it is closed in $\mathbb{C}$ as $f$ is continuous, now option (1) follows.
- For (2) and (4), if we let $z_0 \in Y$ then by the given condition we have $f \equiv 0$ on $U$ by the *Identity theorem* which gives us a contradiction and so $Y = \phi$. Thus it is open and closed in U.
- For  (3), if there is an interior point then there is a nbd of the point inside $X$ and then by *Identity thoerem* we have $f\equiv 0$ on $U$ which is a contradiction, thus $X$ has empty interior.

Comment: Looks fine to me.